# Java read and load images

Tags: java, image, load

i just finish making a Minesweeper game, everything functions perfectly except one thing, the speed of loading the images into he game. I noticed if i have a large number of cells in the game images loads really slow after the mouse click on the cell and it gets faster if i have a smaller number of cells. is there any other way that would make loading images much faster than the one i used? here is the method i used in order to load the images into the game :

```java
   private void draw(Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage gRec =null, flag=null, mine=null, aCount0=null,
            aCount1=null,aCount2 =null,aCount3 =null,aCount4 =null,aCount5 =null,
            aCount6 =null,aCount7 =null,aCount8 = null;
        try {
           gRec = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/blank.gif"));
                flag = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/bombflagged.gif"));
                mine = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/bombdeath.gif"));
                flag = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/bombflagged.gif"));
                aCount0 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open0.gif"));
                aCount1 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open1.gif"));
                aCount2 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open2.gif"));
                aCount3 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open3.gif"));
                aCount4 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open4.gif"));
                aCount5 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open5.gif"));
                aCount6 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open6.gif"));
                aCount7 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open7.gif"));
                aCount8 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/msa_666/Desktop/open8.gif"));
                }
                 catch (IOException e) { 
              e.printStackTrace();
           } 


        if (getCovered() == true && getMarked () == false) {    // gray rectangle
           g.drawImage(gRec,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);

        }
        else if (getCovered()==true && getMarked() ==  true) {  //flag
           g.drawImage(flag,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);

        }
        else if (getCovered()== false && getMined()== true){        //mine
           g.drawImage(mine,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);

        }
        else if ( getCovered() == false && getMined() == false) {   // adjacency count image
            switch (getAdjCount()){
                case 0:
           g.drawImage(aCount0,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 1:
           g.drawImage(aCount1,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 2:
           g.drawImage(aCount2,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 3:
           g.drawImage(aCount3,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;

                case 4:
           g.drawImage(aCount4,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 5:
           g.drawImage(aCount5,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 6:
           g.drawImage(aCount6,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 7:
           g.drawImage(aCount7,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;
                case 8:
           g.drawImage(aCount8,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);
                break;


        }
     }
    }
```

here is the mouse listener to repaint each cell after clicking on it :

```
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      int sRow, sCol;
      sRow= e.getX() / cellHeight;
      sCol = e.getY()/ cellWidth;
      System.out.println(e.getX() +"," +sCol);
      System.out.println(e.getY()+","+sRow);
      if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        if( cells[sRow][sCol].getMarked() == false)     
           uncoverCell(cells[sRow][sCol]);
          // cells[sRow][sCol].setCovered(false);
        System.out.println(cells[sRow][sCol].getMined());
        repaint();
     }
     else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
     }
     else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        if (cells[sRow][sCol].getMarked() == false){
           cells[sRow][sCol].setMarked(true);
                       repaint();

        }
        else {
           cells[sRow][sCol].setMarked(false);          
           repaint();           
        }
     }

     if (allMinesMarked() && allNonMinesUncovered()){
        System.out.println("You Win");
     }
  }


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
     for ( int i=0 ; i <rowCount; i++ ) {
        for (int j=0; j<columnCount; j++) {
           cells[i][j].draw(g);
        }
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, 1+. Please see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell us:

- Just where is `draw(...)` called?
- How do you obtain the Graphics object, g, that is passed into the draw method's parameter?

I'm guessing here since we don't have all of the relevant code, but it looks as if you're re-reading in your images each time you want to display one. If so, don't do this. Read the images in only ***once*** at the start of the program, and then use the Images or perhaps better, ImageIcons, obtained when you need them.

**Edit**
Thanks for posting more code, and this in fact confirms my suspicion: you're re-reading in the image files with every repaint of your GUI. This is highly inefficient and will slow your program down to a crawl. Again, you should read the images into your program *once* and then use them multiple times.

Myself I'd create ImageIcons from the images, and then display them in a JLabel. When there is need to swap images, simply call `setIcon(...)` on the JLabel. This way there's no need to even mess with `paintComponent(...)`.

**Edit 2**
For example (compile and run this):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapIcons {
   private static final int CELL_SIDE_COUNT = 3;
   private ImageCell[] imageCells = new ImageCell[CELL_SIDE_COUNT * CELL_SIDE_COUNT];
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

   public SwapIcons(final GetImages getImages) {
      mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(CELL_SIDE_COUNT, CELL_SIDE_COUNT));
      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));

      for (int i = 0; i < imageCells.length; i++) {
         imageCells[i] = new ImageCell(getImages);
         mainPanel.add(imageCells[i].getImgLabel());
      }
   }

   public JComponent getMainComponent() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui(GetImages getImages) {
      SwapIcons swapIcons = new SwapIcons(getImages);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Click on Icons to Change");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(swapIcons.getMainComponent());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         final GetImages getImages = new GetImages();
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               createAndShowGui(getImages);
            }
         });
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

class ImageCell {
   private JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
   private GetImages getImages;
   private int iconIndex = 0;

   public ImageCell(final GetImages getImages) {
      this.getImages = getImages;
      imgLabel.setIcon(getImages.getIcon(0));
      imgLabel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
   }

   public JLabel getImgLabel() {
      return imgLabel;
   }

   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         iconIndex++;
         iconIndex %= getImages.getIconListSize();
         imgLabel.setIcon(getImages.getIcon(iconIndex));
      }
   }
}

// Simply gets a SpriteSheet and subdivides it into a List of ImageIcons
class GetImages {
   private static final String SPRITE_PATH = "http://th02.deviantart.net/"
         + "fs70/PRE/i/2011/169/0/8/blue_player_sprite_sheet_by_resetado-d3j7zba.png";
   public static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 6;
   public static final int SPRITE_COLS = 6;
   public static final int SPRITE_CELLS = 35;

   private List<ImageIcon> iconList = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

   public GetImages() throws IOException {
      URL imgUrl = new URL(SPRITE_PATH);
      BufferedImage mainImage = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);

      for (int i = 0; i < SPRITE_CELLS; i++) {
         int row = i / SPRITE_COLS;
         int col = i % SPRITE_COLS;
         int x = (int) (((double) mainImage.getWidth() * col) / SPRITE_COLS);
         int y = (int) ((double) (mainImage.getHeight() * row) / SPRITE_ROWS);
         int w = (int) ((double) mainImage.getWidth() / SPRITE_COLS);
         int h = (int) ((double) mainImage.getHeight() / SPRITE_ROWS);
         BufferedImage img = mainImage.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         iconList.add(icon);
      }
   }

   // get the Icon from the List at index position
   public ImageIcon getIcon(int index) {
      if (index < 0 || index >= iconList.size()) {
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
      }

      return iconList.get(index);
   }

   public int getIconListSize() {
      return iconList.size();
   }

}
```

Comment: how can i call setIcon(…) in :
   `  g.drawImage(gRec,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);`
after creating JLabels and icons, i'm confused

Comment: @user2070173: you wouldn't. If you used Icons, you'd not even need to use the `paintComponent(...)` method or have to deal with Graphics objects. Hang on a sec for an example...

Comment: @user2070173: see **Edit 2**

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels answer is good and will work.
And is fine for a standalone app, but for an applet or web start app can further optimize by having one large image and then copying parts of it to the graphics object that is visible, think grids and use function in java.awt.Graphics object (from javadoc):

public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
                int dx1,
                int dy1,
                int dx2,
                int dy2,
                int sx1,
                int sy1,
                int sx2,
                int sy2,
                ImageObserver observer)

Draws as much of the specified area of the specified image as is currently available, scaling it on the fly to fit inside the specified area of the destination drawable surface. Transparent pixels do not affect whatever pixels are already there.

This method returns immediately in all cases, even if the image area to be drawn has not yet been scaled, dithered, and converted for the current output device. If the current output representation is not yet complete then drawImage returns false. As more of the image becomes available, the process that loads the image notifies the specified image observer.

This method always uses the unscaled version of the image to render the scaled rectangle and performs the required scaling on the fly. It does not use a cached, scaled version of the image for this operation. Scaling of the image from source to destination is performed such that the first coordinate of the source rectangle is mapped to the first coordinate of the destination rectangle, and the second source coordinate is mapped to the second destination coordinate. The subimage is scaled and flipped as needed to preserve those mappings.

Parameters:
    img - the specified image to be drawn. This method does nothing if img is null.
    dx1 - the x coordinate of the first corner of the destination rectangle.
    dy1 - the y coordinate of the first corner of the destination rectangle.
    dx2 - the x coordinate of the second corner of the destination rectangle.
    dy2 - the y coordinate of the second corner of the destination rectangle.
    sx1 - the x coordinate of the first corner of the source rectangle.
    sy1 - the y coordinate of the first corner of the source rectangle.
    sx2 - the x coordinate of the second corner of the source rectangle.
    sy2 - the y coordinate of the second corner of the source rectangle.
    observer - object to be notified as more of the image is scaled and converted.
Returns:
    false if the image pixels are still changing; true otherwise.

This is better as it takes a few seconds to make a new connection and download image over internet, so if you have one main image that has all the sub images in a big table then total time to download, load and render will be less. extra logic to copy from an area is trivial maybe .1KB of jar file space :)

Comment: I created a new method which handles reading and loading the images and called it once in the main class and that solved the problem. Anyways, thanks for you help and your explanation